# checkedListBox1 and checkedListBox2

Tags: c#

I want to copy the items checked from checkedListBox1 to checkedListBox2. But in different forms:

Example:

checkedListBox1 = form1
checkedListBox2 = form2

I want to press a button1 (form1) then open a new form (form2), and when form2 open copy the checked items from form1 to form2.

its different because i need with checkedListBox1 & 2, no with checkBox1 & 2.

Comment: No is the same, it is checkbox1 and checbox2, i need with checkedstListBox1 and checkedListBox2.

Comment: What is the problem? Referencing the LB in the other form? (Make it public or make it a property..) - Or the copying of the Items? Simple for Items that are just strings; not quite so simple if they are other types and/ or have Tags of other types. You will need to tell us! - Btw: You should work on your spelling and formatting if you want help here.

Comment: i can't use this code for checkboxListBox:   private void checkBox1_CheckedChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        Form2 a = new Form2();
        a.c = checkBox1.Checked;
        a.ShowDialog();
    }      public partial class Form2 : Form
{
    public bool c;
    public Form2()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    private void Form2_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        checkBox1.Checked = c;
    }
}

Comment: There is a lot of code you can't use. Instead try to answer the questions: What are the Items in the ListBox? Just strings? Did you make the ListBox in the other form public?

Comment: In the ListBox1 & 2 are same Items, and isn't listBox public in form2.

Comment: So all you want is copying the checked state, not the items? You need to reference the listbox, so do make it public or create a public property that references it. If you have a reference to the other form you can simply loop over the items..

Comment: yes, all i wanna is copy the checked state. Can show me a example? I have search one example or the code ago 2 days, and i don't see nothing...

Comment: Have you resolved your problems?

Answer (score 0):

You have really two problems in one:

- How to copy the checked state of a `CheckedListBox`
- and how to reference a Control that sits in **another** Form?

Here a the two answer, one is almost obligatory, the other one just of many ways to solve the problem..

- To copy the boolean checked state one has to use these two functions [`GetItemChecked(Item)`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.checkedlistbox.getitemchecked%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) and [`SetItemChecked(Item, value)`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.checkedlistbox.getitemchecked%28v=vs.110%29.aspx).

(Note: There is also a second pair of functions [`GetItemCheckState(Item)`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.checkedlistbox.getitemchecked%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) and [`SetItemCheckState(Item, state)`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.checkedlistbox.getitemchecked%28v=vs.110%29.aspx). Those are for `CheckedListBox` where you want to use a **third**, `Indeterminate` state. Also note that to create such a state you must use code. And there is no property of the `CheckedListBox` to allow for it; this is different than with `CheckBoxes`, which have a `ThreeState` property!)

So **if** you can reference two `CheckedListBoxes clb1 and clb2` you can copy the checkmarks like this:

```
for (int i = 0; i < clb1 .Items.Count; i++)
     clb2.SetItemChecked(i, clb1.GetItemChecked(i));
```

This simple example assumes that the second one has at least the same number of items and that the corresponding items are in the same order.

- The other, very common problem is **how to reference controls in another form?**

There are several options and if you google you will find a large number of examples.

I'll show you the simplest one, given that you want to open the 2nd form from a `Button` on `Form1`:

First two class level variables;

```
Form2 form2 = null;                // keep references to the other form
CheckedListBox clb2 = null;        // ..and the CLB on it!
```

Note that the refrence to the form is optional, but chances are you will want it later..Also note the code assumes that you have created a Form2 class in the designer..

Now you can open the second form and store a reference to **its** `CheckedListBox` **with the 1st** form:

```
private void openForm2Button_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    form2 = new Form2();
    clb2 = form2.Controls["yourListBoxName"];  // use the real name of the clb!!
    form2.Show();
}
```

After adding items to both boxes and checking a few items you can then clone the boolean checked state:

```
private void copyChecksButton_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if (clb2 != null)
        for (int i = 0; i < clb1.Items.Count; i++)
                clb2.SetItemChecked(i, clb2.GetItemChecked(i));
}
```

Note that this will crash if the second box has less items that the first one. You could use `Math.Min(clb1.Items, clb2.Items)` in the loop condition to prevent the crash..

Comment: Really, I don't understand your tutorial, i try to user your code, but alway i have error. I don't know where put this code: for (int i = 0; i < clb1 .Items.Count; i++)
     clb2.SetItemChecked(i, clb1.GetItemChecked(i));         and this: Form2 form2 = null;                // keep references to the other form
CheckedListBox clb2 = null;        // ..and the CLB on it!

Comment: The second are variables. Put the at class level, as I wrote! (E.G. after the form's constructor: public Form1()  {  InitializeComponent(); }` - The former does the copying. I thought you want to copy the checked state upon a button click? Well, put it there! - The important part is understanding how to keep valid references to everything you want to work with!